# JObject returning empty data

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

Im trying to return detailed feedback in my API so created a class:

```
public class Notify
{
   public class Root
   {
     Public string Error {get; set;}
     Public Details Details {get; set;}
   }

  public class Details
   {
     public string FeedbackText {get; set;}
     ....
   }
}
```

In my class i populate the object with

```
public JObject NotifyUser()
{
     var r = new Notify.Root 
     { 
     Error = "Some error",
     Details = new Notify.Details
           { 
             FeedbackText = "Something to do"
            }
     };

     return JObject.Parse(DoSomethingWithJson(r));
}
```

`DoSomethingWithJson` is a `string` method and passing in the object to modify the data.

In my API i have

```
var currentValue = NotifyUser(); // I see the Json and values in this variable but next line doesnt display the values only the Json fields
return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, currentValue);
```

but it just returns the JSON fields without any data against any field.
I convert it to a string and everything appears including the text assigned to each field but the response is listed as text and not JSON.

Ive tried converting the code to `JsonConvert.SerialiseObject` but if its in a **string format** it shows the data otherwise its empty properties (i would like the response to be encoded as json).

Im not sure why its doing this? What have i missed? I did search around but most were targeting old versions so i feel im doing something wrong here.

Comment: This won't compile. There's no string to parse in `NotifyUser` either. What are you trying to do? If you want to convert `r` to a JSON string, use `JsonConvert.Serialize(r)`. JSON is text with a specific format, not a type like `JObject`. That's what JSON.NET uses to allow LINQ queries over JSON.

Comment: @Computer Do you think it is very smart and respectfull to  add DoSomethingWithJson(r) to your post without showing the code?

Comment: *but it just returns the JSON fields without any data against any field.* -- this could be because you are actually using System.Text.Json.  See e.g. [How can I serialize a Newtonsoft JToken to JSON using System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65386083) or [ASP.Net core - blank response when returning a JObject property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72224818).  But please provide a [mcve] so we can confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can not be even compilled. You can use Parse only for a json string. But you have a c# object. You should try to compile your code before asking the question. The last line should be

```
return JObject.FromObject(r);
```

But probably you don't need to convert it to JObject since APi action will automatically serialize it to a json string. It doesnt matter if it  is a json object or c# object.

Comment: It definitely compiled otherwise no reason for me to post the question as the error would give it away. I may have had a typo above but it compiled before i even posted

Comment: @Computer it didn't. `Parse` expects a string, `r` is a `Root`. There's no string in the code you posted. You probably pasted the wrong snippet

Comment: Sorry i miss typed - ive amended my original post. I tried FromObject but considering i missed off the key part of the code, the above didnt work - apologies

Comment: @Computer  fixed your question